# Hamiltonian decomposability of 4- regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, hamiltonicity

If a 4 regular graph is hamiltonian can we say it is hamiltonian decomposable ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

The MathWorld article on [Hamiltonian decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonDecomposition.html) gives the following examples of regular graphs which are Hamiltonian but not Hamiltonian decomposable:

[image]

All of these happen to be $4$-regular, which would probably be disappointing to someone who was looking for a different kind of example, but is exactly what you are looking for.

In the first four examples, it is easy to see *why* thy are not Hamiltonian decomposable: there are two parts connected by only two edges, and once a single Hamiltonian cycle is removed, they become disconnected. The last two examples don't have this property, so they are not Hamiltonian decomposeable for some other, subtler reason.